# Hibernate jdbc no suitable driver found

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I'm receiving the dreaded No suitable driver found error when using Hibernate. I'm pretty sure the driver jar is in the classpath as I can do `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. In fact for now I just call this before building the session factory and my code works. But is this 'safe'? Why is this happening? Here is my config:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

    <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

Thank you

Comment: If that's the case it could be that you're experiencing class loading issues. Where is the jdbc driver jar located in comparison to hibernate?

Comment: All my jars are located in `WEB-INF/lib`. It's very weird, like I said, I just call `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before setting up the session factory and everything works, I can query my database and data is returned. I'm just wondering if my solution is stable and safe...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the JAR is in the `CLASSPATH`.  You'd get a `NoClassDefFound` exception if that wasn't the case.

No suitable driver usually means that the connection URL syntax isn't correct for the given driver.

MySQL needs `"jdbc:mysql://server:3306/database"` - yours looks correct.

If it can't resolve localhost, you'll have a problem.  Maybe 127.0.0.1 will work better.

Is MySQL listening on port 3306?

Does the database you asked to connected to exist?  Can you log in via the MySQL client and see tables and data?

Comment: A driver should accept any well-formed URL (ie adhering to the URL syntax established for that specific driver), even if the specified host or port is not available to connect. The DriverManager establishes connection in two steps: it first iterates over all available drivers asking them if they would accept the specified URL, the first driver to accept it will then be used to actually establish connection. The error in the question comes up in the first part if no driver accepted the URL.

Comment: Whenever I've gotten that error, it meant I had a syntax error for the driver I was using.  So I'd see it if I gave the correct MySQL URL syntax and used an Oracle JDBC driver JAR or incorrect Oracle URL syntax.  If that's how you mean it, then we agree.

Comment: That is what I meant, as you are talking about resolving hosts and ports. That doesn't come into play until after the driver accepted the URL.